# Force Windows 10 Login after Wake-On-LAN from Raspberry Pi

Tags: remote, windows

Trying to set up a Raspberry Pi as a Steam Link device for my PC.  I have both devices connected via ethernet to my router, and I've configured the PC to allow Wake On LAN.
I managed to get the Pi to successfully send a Wake-On-LAN command to the PC at startup, then fire up Steam Link.
The PC is configured to start Steam on startup.

The problem is that when I log into the Pi and it connects through Steam Link, the screen shows black until I have actually signed into the PC fully.
As I play with the controller on the Pi, it plays sound effects as I select different menu items, but the screen just shows black with the cursor visible in the corner.

My temporary solution is to auto sign-in at startup, but I am wondering if there is any way to remotely force the PC to sign in to the admin account via the terminal, preferably something that requires both the username and password, to maintain some level of security.
The solution must be something that can be run through rc.local or similar.
The Pi has no keyboard or mouse attached, only a single Bluetooth controller.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Are you sure that the PC which has configured to start Steam on startup, run it as administrator? Maybe some functionality of PC's graphic card is disabled before login. You'll get a better answer if you ask this question on other communities like [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Google it: `steam link black screen with sound`. Check these links: https://steamcommunity.com/app/353380/discussions/0/483367798510147290/
https://steamcommunity.com/app/612880/discussions/0/1479856439030942762/